# Can I use Google fonts to use through my Android app?

Tags: android, fonts, google-fonts

I am developing an Android app for create simple posts to others. Now I want to add fonts in my app for others to apply fonts to their projects without any copyright problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From official android developer documentation

> Android 8.0 (`API` level 26) and **Android Support Library 26**
>   introduce support for APIs to request fonts from a provider
>   application instead of bundling files into the APK or letting the
>   `APK` download fonts. The feature is available on devices running
>   Android API versions 14 and higher through the **Support Library 26**.

please check this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts) to know how to use them